# How do i set text size in a text view programmatically according to the width of a text view.?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, textview

The text view i am using in the application is supposed to be single line and has a predefined width which may contain text fetched from database ranging from single word to maximum 3 words. I found a link in stack overflow for adjusting the text size according to height of the text view but i am looking for something more particular to width of text view.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but you might find faster ways posted. The incrementation in the loop does cost some time, so use sparingly in a single layout.

```
    Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x; //Get screen width. There are other ways to do this too.

    int tSize = 10;
    tv.setTextSize(tSize); //tv is your TextView

    while (tv.getPaint().measureText((String) tv.getText())
            < width){
        tSize++;
        tv.setTextSize(tSize); //Increment up till screen width is filled.
        }
```